# C++ constexpr function-definition is not allowed

Tags: c++, constexpr, local-functions

I'm trying to learn C++, specifically C++11 since we mostly study C, and I've ran into an error while trying to test what "constexpr" can do.

Test 1:

```
#include <iostream>;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 4;
    constexpr int Sum(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
    cout << Sum(x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Test 2:

```
#include <iostream>;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 4;
    constexpr int Sum() {return 3+4;}
    cout << Sum();
    return 0;
}
```

On both cases, it gave me the following errors:

E:\C++\Lesson1\main.cpp|9|error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token|
E:\C++\Lesson1\main.cpp|10|error: 'Sum' was not declared in this scope|

Am I doing something wrong or I have to do something to the compiler? (Using Code Blocks and I have C++11 enabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are local function definitions illegal in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290885/why-are-local-function-definitions-illegal-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving your `constexpr` function definition outside of `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Your problem**

You put a semicolon after a preprocessor directive (`#include`). You should never do that, unless `#define`-ing something. This is making the compiler go nuts. Also, in addition to that, you **cannot** define a function within a function. You must define it outside, in global or class scope.

**Solution**

Remove the semicolon behind `#include <iostream>`.
Move the constexpr definition *above* `main()`.

Comment: Oh yeah, that was a mistake on my part.