# Why are local function definitions illegal in C++?

Tags: c++, language-design, local-functions

It comes across as odd to me that local function definitions are illegal. As things stand now, I doubt it would be too hard to implement, and the erasure of what could be a potential feature (like in python for example) for no reason at all seems strange, especially for a language like C++, where you can shoot yourself in the foot if you want to. The illegality of local function definitions seems doubly so strange if things like this are allowed.

```
int main()
{
    void func(); // Allowed?

    class BypassRules {
    public:
        static void func() { return; }
    };

    BypassRules::func();
    func();

    return 0;
}

void func() { return; }
```

Oddly enough, local function 'Declarations' are allowed, but definitions are not. And the rule on local function definitions not being allowed can be easily bypassed by writing a class encapsulator. So, could I have some clarification? Why are local class definitions classified as 'illegal' in C++?

Comment: Don't know whether it actually would've broken something, but if you need a local function, you may as well go with a lambda.

Comment: C++ offers you class methods, which are local to a class. Static functions are "local" to a translation unit. As others said, lambdas exist as well. The main reason why C++ does not have local functions is because C does not have them. And as it stands now, there is no reason to add them because there are alternatives.

Comment: Declarations aren't local, they declare something in the enclosing namespace.

Comment: GCC provides nested functions as a language extension. But only in C when using a `gnu` variant of the language standard.

Comment: You can put functions in an anonymous namespace to make them local to a translation unit. Or you can use a lambda inside a function, to make a function local callable - `void f() { const auto my_add = [](int a, int b) { return a + b; }; std::cout << my_add(1, 2); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Oddly enough, local function 'Declarations' are allowed, but definitions are not. And the rule on local function definitions not being allowed can be easily bypassed by writing a class encapsulator. So, could I have some clarification? Why are local class definitions classified as 'illegal' in C++?

Illegal because they don't make much sense, whether it may be defining a function inside a function or a class inside a function like `main()`.

But then you can always use workarounds, such as:

- For functions you can always use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), which acts as an anonymous temporary function, can be called inside `main` plus be used within function parameters as well.

It can be invoked whenever necessary and subsequently discarded like a throw-away function, but it does the job - whatever you would expect from a function.

Example:

```cpp
int main() 
{ 
  // Define within the scope of main()
  auto temp = [](int x)
  { std::cout<< x; 
  }
  temp(10); // call like a function
}
```

---

- For classes, use static functions, (being local to the translation unit) with public access specifiers (as you did in your question).

Example:

```cpp
int main()
{
   class temp
   {  public:
      static void a()
      {  std::cout<< 10;
      }
   };
   temp::a();
}
```

---

Output for both cases: `10`

Provided there are alternatives approaches like the ones above to *define* a function/class/struct inside `main()`, there isn't really much of a point to make them legal. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: coming from Pascal, I actually see that they're extremely useful amd make a lot of sense. Sometimes you have a huge function to split into smaller functions. The subfunction is only used in that function so making them available to other functions doesn't make sense. Besides being a nested function they can access all the father's variables without needing to pass a lot of variables

Comment: @phuclv Thats what a lambda already does for you in C++. You can choose to get a copy of all values using `=` inside lambda's scope as well. (or specify particular variables as you want)

Comment: @phuclv C++11 isn't new

Comment: it's relatively new compared to when the first C and C++ standards. And even the standards are decades newer than when the language first appeared

Comment: @phuclv There are inumerous resources on it everywhere on the internet, so many that its definitely not something which the OP could not have googled-out to find as an alternative for defining a function inside a function. Stack Overflow has plenty of threads on the `lambda` tag too, with 4 users recieving a gold for it..your living in an era where C++20 is prevalent, no question of a C++11 feature being unknown.